# What is wrong with pip?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install a library in anaconda but i have the next error (with any library I tried:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000051CECC0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/worldcloud/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000051CEDA0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/worldcloud/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000000051CEA90>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/worldcloud/
```

I want to know if exists a solution for this problem, or in other case, if I could download and charge the packages with other way.

I'm using Windows 10 and python 2.7

Comment: Please read this (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and this (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Especially  considering this idea,

Write a title that summarizes the specific problem
The title is the first thing potential answerers will see, and if your title isn't interesting, they won't read the rest. So make it count

The way this question is written does not describe the specific problem you are having in a quick and easy to understand way.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Is it possible you have an old version of pip that doesn't know to use TLS (https) communications? Find out which version you are using with

```
pip --version
```

You need to be using pip 9.0.3 or higher. If you aren't, you might solve the issue with

```
conda update pip
```

Alternatively, perhaps you have set up a proxy that pip can't use or isn't using.

Answer (score 0):

In the command line of your PC, type `ping pypi.org` and see what happens. If there is no response, you have an external network issue. If there is one, try giving pip elevated permissions *just this one time* to see if it works.